# Oracle SQL regexp_substr non-capturing/optional group

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regex-group

The expression:

```
Reassigning definition: (\d+) from: \[(\d+)\] to: \[(\d+)\].+?\.(?: Target definition = (\d+))?.*
```

correctly produces the following matches:

```
Group 1.    24-30   494801
Group 2.    38-45   8280955
Group 3.    52-59   8336297
Group 4.    103-109 494767
```

for the input string:

```
Reassigning definition: 494801 from: [8280955] to: [8336297], advancing due dates. Target definition = 494767.
```

and the first 3 matches for the input string:

```
Reassigning definition: 494801 from: [8280955] to: [8336297], advancing due dates.
```

with JavaScript, Python, PHP, and GoLang flavors (see https://regex101.com/r/Br66wm/3), but does not with SQL regexp-substr:

```
with
  input_string as
  (
    select 'Reassigning definition: 494801 from: [8280955] to: [8336297], advancing dates. Target definition = 494767.' as test_string from dual
    union all
    select 'Reassigning definition: 494801 from: [8280955] to: [8336297], advancing dates.' as test_string from dual
   ),
   pattern_string as
   (
     select 'Reassigning definition: (\d+) from: \[(\d+)\] to: \[(\d+)\].+?\.(?: Target definition = (\d+))?.*$' as pattern_string from dual
   )
select
  regexp_substr(i.test_string, p.pattern_string, 1, 1, null, 1) as group_1,
  regexp_substr(i.test_string, p.pattern_string, 1, 1, null, 2) as group_2,
  regexp_substr(i.test_string, p.pattern_string, 1, 1, null, 3) as group_3,
  regexp_substr(i.test_string, p.pattern_string, 1, 1, null, 4) as group_4
from
  input_string i, pattern_string p;
```

where the 4th group is always `null`. What's wrong with my usage of non-capturing groups? Basically, the following sentence is optional in my input test strings:

```
 Target definition = 494767.
```

Comment: I don't know Oracle's Regex implementation (POSIX-based?) in detail, but it might not support this non-capturing group syntax.

Comment: @dnoeth yeah, that's what I suspect is the problem here. If this isn't supported, I would like to understand how else to capture the optional group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit too much to put into a comment so I'll write it here. If it doesn't make sense, I'll just remove it.

If you're always looking for *digits* in those strings (not related to what surrounds them), then it could be simplified to

```
SQL> with
  2    input_string as
  3    (
  4      select 'Reassigning definition: 494801 from: [8280955] to: [8336297], advancing dates. Target definition = 494767.' as test_string from dual
  5      union all
  6      select 'Reassigning definition: 494801 from: [8280955] to: [8336297], advancing dates.' as test_string from dual
  7     )
  8  select regexp_substr(test_string, '\d+', 1, 1) grp1,
  9         regexp_substr(test_string, '\d+', 1, 2) grp2,
 10         regexp_substr(test_string, '\d+', 1, 3) grp3,
 11         regexp_substr(test_string, '\d+', 1, 4) grp4
 12  from input_string;

GRP1       GRP2       GRP3       GRP4
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
494801     8280955    8336297    494767
494801     8280955    8336297

SQL>
```

---

Or, option which doesn't have fixed number of *groups* (though, layout is different from what you wanted):

```
SQL> with
  2    input_string as
  3    (
  4      select 'Reassigning definition: 494801 from: [8280955] to: [8336297], advancing dates. Target definition = 494767.' as test_string from dual
  5      union all
  6      select 'Reassigning definition: 494801 from: [8280955] to: [8336297], advancing dates.' as test_string from dual
  7     )
  8  select column_value grp_rn,
  9         regexp_substr(test_string, '\d+', 1, column_value) grp
 10  from input_String cross join
 11    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 12                        connect by level <= regexp_count(test_string, '\d+')
 13                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

 GRP_RN GRP
------- ----------
      1 494801
      2 8280955
      3 8336297
      4 494767
      1 494801
      2 8280955
      3 8336297

7 rows selected.
```

Comment: Hmm, you're right, I only really care about the numbers in the string, and given what I have, it's OK to assume they will be in the said order. So your #1 works for me in the absence of a more elegant way of capturing the groups/numbers, including optional ones.

Comment: actually, I decided to use a separate pattern expression for the optional group.

Answer (score 0):

Because the POSIX-based regex implementation does not seem to support non-capturing groups, and the captured groups of `regex_substr` are not readily available as separate columns, I went with the following, which basically uses a different regex for the optional group.

```
with
  input_string as
  (
    select 'Reassigning definition: 494801 from: [8280955] to: [8336297], advancing dates. Target definition = 494767.' as test_string from dual
    union all
    select 'Reassigning definition: 494767 from: [8336297] to: [8369944], advancing dates.' as test_string from dual
   ),
   pattern_string as
   (
     select 'Reassigning definition: (\d+) from: \[(\d+)\] to: \[(\d+)\]' as pattern_string from dual
   )
select
  regexp_substr(i.test_string, p.pattern_string, 1, 1, null, 1) as group_1,
  regexp_substr(i.test_string, p.pattern_string, 1, 1, null, 2) as group_2,
  regexp_substr(i.test_string, p.pattern_string, 1, 1, null, 3) as group_3,
  regexp_substr(i.test_string, 'Target definition = (\d+)', 1, 1, null, 1) as group_4
from
  input_string i, pattern_string p;
```